# Search for %, $ using :Ag

Tags: command-line, the-silver-searcher

How can I search for queries including `%`, `$` and the likes? I tried to prefix then with '\', enclosing in quotes, but it only makes it worse:

```
:Ag "$r"
|| ERR: Error: No query. What do you want to search for?

:Ag "\$r"
No matches for ""\$r""

:Ag \\$r
|| ERR: Bad regex! pcre_compile() failed at position 1: \ at end of pattern
|| If you meant to search for a literal string, run ag with -Q

:Ag -Q "\\$r"
:Ag -Q \\$r
No Error, but finds god knows what

:Ag "\%whatever"
|| ERR: Error: No query. What do you want to search for?

:Ag "%whatever"
E499: Empty file name for '%' or '#', only works with ":p:h"
```

Comment: What happens if you use *single* quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the following?

```
:Ag \\$
```

Comment: I have updated the question with more examples including this one.

Comment: @firedev Try `:Ag \\\$`. '\\' to escape '\' and '\$' to escape `$`. `:Ag '\$'` (with single quotes) also works if you don't want a ton of slashes. EDIT: Ugh, same stuff here....

Comment: For %. That requires double slashes inside single quotes and four outside: `:Ag '\\%'` or `:Ag \\\\%`.